# using GEKKO to simulate a State Space equation with huge arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, gekko

I'm trying to use gekko to simulate a state space equation with input (uu_DF) and initial condition (init_cond_DF).
The code works fine for small arrays (e.g., 3*3). However in high ranked A,B,C matrices (rank(A)=4553) the code comes to the following error
Please note that I'm using google colab to run this code since my laptop (i5 CPU @ 2.67 GHz + 4GB RAM) is not able to run it!

```
apm 35.196.244.129_gk_model5 <br><pre> ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.2
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            1
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :        27318
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :        27318
   Equations    :            0
   Residuals    :            0
 
 @error: Model Undefined
 Error, did not find at least one of A, B, or C matrices: 
 statespace1.a.txt
 statespace1.b.txt
 statespace1.c.txt
 Stopping...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-bb51a821614c> in <module>()
     14 #m.options.nodes = 2
     15 m.open_folder
---> 16 m.solve() # (GUI=True)
     17 
     18 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gekko/gekko.py in solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   2172             #print APM error message and die
   2173             if (debug >= 1) and ('@error' in response):
-> 2174                 raise Exception(response)
   2175 
   2176             #load results

Exception:  @error: Model Undefined
 Error, did not find at least one of A, B, or C matrices: 
 statespace1.a.txt
 statespace1.b.txt
 statespace1.c.txt
 Stopping...
```

My code is shown below

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


# Importing matrices via .csv file
M = pd.read_csv(r'M.csv',header=None)
C = pd.read_csv (r'C.csv',header=None)
K = pd.read_csv (r'K.csv',header=None)
X0 = pd.read_csv (r'X0.csv',header=None)
F = pd.read_csv (r'F.csv',header=None)

# Some prerequisite calculations
dim = len(X0)
DF_eye = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(dim,dtype='uint8'))
DF_zeros = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((dim, dim),dtype='uint8'))
BB = DF_eye # coefficient inside B matrix
M_inv_DF =  pd.DataFrame(np.linalg.inv(M))
CC = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2*dim, 2*dim),dtype='uint8')) # controller matrix

# System dynamics matrix
A_Row1_DF = pd.concat((DF_zeros, DF_eye), axis=1)
A_Row2_DF = pd.concat((M_inv_DF * K, M_inv_DF * C), axis=1)
A_DF = pd.concat((A_Row1_DF, A_Row2_DF), axis=0)

# System input matrix
B_Row1_DF = pd.concat((DF_zeros, DF_zeros), axis=1)
B_Row2_DF = pd.concat((DF_zeros, M_inv_DF * BB), axis=1)
B_DF = pd.concat((B_Row1_DF, B_Row2_DF), axis=0)

# Input matrix
uu_DF = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((dim, 1))), pd.DataFrame(F)), axis=0)

# Initial condition matrix
init_cond_DF = pd.concat((X0, X0), axis=0)

    
m = GEKKO()  # create GEKKO model

x,y,u = m.state_space(A_DF,B_DF,CC,D=None)


m.time = np.linspace(0,120,2*dim)
u[0].value = np.array(uu_DF)
x[0].value = np.array(init_cond_DF)
m.options.imode = 4

m.solve(GUI=True) # (GUI=True)


plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(m.time,u[0].value,'r-',label=r'$Input$')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(m.time,x[0].value,'b--',label=r'$Initial condition$')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.plot(m.time,x[4],'.-',label=r'$x_4$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I tested my code for the A matrices of ranks: **82, 126, 170, 214, 258, 298, 342, 386, 430, 474** the first **four** systems were solved with a *final time* of **120 sec** and the *solution time* was at most **4.36 sec**. The next **five** systems were solved with a *final time* of **60 sec** and the *solution time* increases exponentially to **100.13 sec**. The system with the A matrix of rank **474** is the last one that gekko affords its simulation with a *final time* of **10 sec** and the *solution time* of **113.5 sec**. with the *Execution time* of **8700.554s**!
In my next try for the A matrix of rank **902** with a *final time* of **10 sec** gekko raises the following error:

```
Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-897bb2f533e0> in <module>()
     10 #m.options.NODES = 4
     11 #m.open_folder()
---> 12 m.solve() # (GUI=True)

________________________________________
1 frames
________________________________________
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gekko/gk_post_solve.py in load_JSON(self)
     11 ## options.JSON has all APM options
     12 def load_JSON(self):
---> 13     f = open(os.path.join(self._path,'options.json'))
     14     data = json.load(f)
     15     f.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpajn2dnt_gk_model1/options.json'
```

[image]

Comment: What does the text file `gk_model0.apm` look like when you open the run folder with `m.open_folder()`? It looks like there was a problem creating the files `statespace1.a.txt`, `statespace1.b.txt`, or `statespace1.c.txt`.

Comment: All of the files are being created properly except: `options.json`, `results.json`, `results.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to simulate a state space model then `scipy.signal` may be a good option. There are additional examples with Scipy.signal [here](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/StateSpaceModel).

[image: State Space Solution]

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

A = [[0.0,1.0],[-0.25,-0.5]]
B = [[0.0],[0.75]]
C = [[1.0,0.0]]
D = [0.0]
sys3 = signal.StateSpace(A,B,C,D)
t = np.linspace(0,30,200)
u = np.zeros(len(t))
u[5:100] = 1.0 # first step input
u[100:] = 2.0  # second step input
t3,y3,x3 = signal.lsim(sys3,u,t)

from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
xgk,ygk,ugk = m.state_space(A,B,C,D=None)
m.time = t; ugk[0].value = u
m.options.imode = 4
m.options.nodes = 4
m.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t3,y3,'k-',lw=2)
plt.plot(t,ygk[0].value,'y--',lw=2)
plt.plot(t,u,'r-')
plt.legend(['y Scipy','y Gekko','u'],loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

If you need to use Gekko for Model Predictive Control then you can use the [`dense=False` matrix option](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/LinearStateSpace) that converts the matrix to a sparse form. This helps for large-scale systems. There is also the [Time Series (ARX)](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/ARXTimeSeries) and [Discrete State Space](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/DiscreteStateSpace) form.

Comment: Please see my edits on this post. It seems that gekko is not able to handle big files for solution.

Comment: If you need simulation only, did you try the Scipy.Signal package? Gekko can do simulation but it is built as an optimizer such as for Model Predictive Control. There is configuration overhead, such as when you define an MV or CV with extra equations that may be unnecessary for simulation: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ControllerObjective One quick thing you could try is to set `m.options.CV_TYPE=2` to reduce the number of CV equations if they aren't needed for your simulation.

Comment: Another thing that you can try with Gekko in simulation is to switch to a sequential solution mode with `m.options.IMODE=7`. This should give the same solution as `IMODE=4` but it processes the simulation steps one at a time instead of solving with a simultaneous approach. Unfortunately, we don't have all of the required files (such as `M.csv`) to reproduce your solution to give you more specific suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate comments. Unfortunately Scipy.Signal package is not able to afford these huge matrices it raises an error about this. I just emailed matrix files.

Comment: What was the result of using `m.options.CV_TYPE=2` and `m.options.IMODE=7`? Did either one help?

Comment: Using `m.options.CV_TYPE=2` and `m.options.IMODE=7` for the system with A matrix of rank **474** with a _final time_ of **10 sec** decreased the _solution time_ from **113.5 sec** to a maximum of **14.3 sec**, and _Execution time_ from **8700.554 sec** to **24.6 sec**. Then I try to use the same method for higher orders.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. Keep us updated on your progress with higher orders.

Comment: I checked Gekko (`m.options.IMODE=7` and `m.options.CV_TYPE=2`) with different matrix ranks. I also used _Python Control Systems Library_ **lsim** to simulate the State Space models. As shown in the bar chart (post edited) due to the configuration overhead (simultaneous optimization) it takes much longer for Gekko to simulate the state space. If there was an option to cancel optimization it could be the best option.

Comment: Some of the overhead associated with optimization and nonlinear solution methods may be contributing to the difference in time. Gekko is unique in that models of different types can be simulated or optimized together. These include discrete-time, continuous-time, data-driven (neural networks), nonlinear differential equations, linear time-series, etc. A challenge with creating a package that solves all of these problems is that there are tradeoffs that customized solvers (such as lsim) will be able to exploit for a faster solution.